# Разобрать (parse) JSON, возвращаемый WEB сервисом и отсортировать полученную таблицу по столбцу

Tags: python, парсер, pandas

Есть код:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

res = (pd.read_json('https://api.kucoin.com/v1/open/tick'))
print(res)
```

Вывод такой: (первые три строки)

```
    code                                               data  \
0     OK  {'coinType': 'BTC', 'trading': True, 'symbol':...   
1     OK  {'coinType': 'ETH', 'trading': True, 'symbol':...   
2     OK  {'coinType': 'ETH', 'trading': True, 'symbol':...
```

Каждая строка на самом деле должна быть длинее, после 'symbol' еще  много данных.
Как отсортировать по алфавиту, по ключу 'symbol'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [104]: import requests

In [105]: r = requests.get('https://api.kucoin.com/v1/open/tick')

In [108]: df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['data']).sort_values(['symbol'])

In [109]: df
Out[109]:
           buy        change  changeRate coinType coinTypePair       datetime  feeRate       high  lastDealPrice  \
93    0.000001  2.000000e-08      0.0165     ACAT          BTC  1519824458000    0.001   0.000001       0.000001
94    0.000015  1.000000e-06      0.0714     ACAT          ETH  1519824458000    0.001   0.000017       0.000015
95    0.000103  1.100000e-05      0.1196     ACAT          NEO  1519824458000    0.001   0.000139       0.000103
129   0.000321  4.010000e-06      0.0125      ACT          BCH  1519824458000    0.001   0.000327       0.000324
130   0.000036 -9.800000e-07     -0.0266      ACT          BTC  1519824458000    0.001   0.000038       0.000036
131   0.000437 -1.300000e-05     -0.0289      ACT          ETH  1519824458000    0.001   0.000460       0.000437
67    0.000002  1.000000e-07      0.0538      ADB          BTC  1519824458000    0.001   0.000002       0.000002
..         ...           ...         ...      ...          ...            ...      ...        ...            ...
200   0.015610 -7.330000e-04     -0.0449      XLR          ETH  1519824458000    0.001   0.017497       0.015610
39    0.001329 -1.202500e-04     -0.0830      XRB          BTC  1519824458000    0.001   0.001525       0.001329
40    0.015960 -1.681000e-03     -0.0953      XRB          ETH  1519824458000    0.001   0.018500       0.015955
41   13.600039 -1.215825e+00     -0.0789      XRB         USDT  1519824458000    0.001  16.390557      14.189994
23    0.000012 -1.290000e-06     -0.0942      ZPT          BTC  1519824458000    0.001   0.000014       0.000012
24    0.000151 -1.300000e-05     -0.0793      ZPT          ETH  1519824458000    0.001   0.000173       0.000151
25    0.000988 -5.100000e-05     -0.0491      ZPT          NEO  1519824458000    0.001   0.001100       0.000988

           low       sell  sort    symbol  trading           vol       volValue
93    0.000001   0.000001   100  ACAT-BTC     True  1.673705e+06       2.149871
94    0.000014   0.000016     0  ACAT-ETH     True  4.792000e+06      73.560591
95    0.000088   0.000108     0  ACAT-NEO     True  2.662468e+06     291.709675
129   0.000284   0.000326     0   ACT-BCH     True  3.788311e+03       1.216343
130   0.000034   0.000036     0   ACT-BTC     True  5.012917e+05      18.393863
131   0.000431   0.000438     0   ACT-ETH     True  2.595300e+05     116.162466
67    0.000002   0.000002   100   ADB-BTC     True  1.213589e+06       2.298013
..         ...        ...   ...       ...      ...           ...            ...
200   0.015054   0.016863     0   XLR-ETH     True  1.082343e+03      17.321336
39    0.001280   0.001333     0   XRB-BTC     True  2.229414e+05     314.747675
40    0.015608   0.016197     0   XRB-ETH     True  5.373682e+04     927.325583
41   13.500090  13.989962   100  XRB-USDT     True  2.261786e+04  339405.246400
23    0.000012   0.000013   100   ZPT-BTC     True  1.282672e+06      16.983218
24    0.000149   0.000152     0   ZPT-ETH     True  8.591434e+06    1390.161550
25    0.000975   0.001033     0   ZPT-NEO     True  3.446997e+05     352.053972

[278 rows x 16 columns]
```

Comment: Спасибо, получается.

Comment: Еще вопрос: что за номера стоят первыми в этих строках? Можно ли от них как-то избавиться? Если я вывожу на печать только ['symbol'], номера перед ними все равно остаются.

Comment: @aaasakurra, это индекс DataFrame. Избавиться легче всего при сохранении в файл (CSV, Excel, HTML, HDF5, Feather, Parquet, etc) или БД, указав `index=False`

Comment: Прошу подсказать еще один раз: как теперь из этого отсортированного списка выдернуть нужные мне строки? Я пользовался циклом (for, затем if '  ' in df, то print i) Теперь это выдает мне ошибку string indices must be integers

Comment: @aaasakurra, лучше задать отдельный вопрос с укзанием критерия выбора нужных вам строк... ;-) PS работая с Pandas в 95% случаев можно обойтись без цикла...